# CollapsableTableView, UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency error in iOS6

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios6

I have an iPhone application which uses a CollapsableTableView. After upgrading to iOS 6 I get a crash in the application with the following error.

> "A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View  is associated with CollapsableTableViewHeaderViewController: 0x8a93430. Clear this association before associating this view with CollapsableTableViewHeaderViewController: 0x8a943c0"

It would be rather helpful if I anyone of you has come across the same problem in order to find a solution for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail. When does the crash occur? What is the code that relates to the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using something like this:

[self.addSubView collapsableViewController.view];

This kind of association is not allowed, since one view can't be associated with two view controllers as stated in the error description.

Comment: Thank you appreciate your thoughts.